# Replicate "scribbly" effect in 3d with Blender 2.8

Tags: animation

Looking for advice on replicating this common effect in 2d animation:

[image]

I've tried a few things, nothing came close to looking good. Ideally it would be the same effect, but in the 3rd dimension as well.

The closest I came (which still looked quite poor) was with shape keys and randomizing the vertices each frame. It looked alright on the edges only, but the effect wouldn't be there in the middle of the mesh.

Any ideas or even someone having replicated this effect before (I tried searching but found nothing) would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have a look into *Grease pencil* + *Noise modifier*: https://youtu.be/w_lFKlswc70?t=67

Comment: This looks like the same effect, being 2d still - I'm looking to replicate it in 3d